# WPML - SQL query to get post by current language

Tags: wordpress, localization, wpml

I'm using WPML and need a custom search query (The default search of wordpress is not working in my case).
Let say my query is:
`"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE %s% AND [WPML_CURRENT_LANGUAGE_CONDITION]"`;

Please help me check which table I should care for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After checking with my friend, he helped me out and this query is find post in current language only.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_icl_translations post_trans
ON wp_posts.ID = post_trans.element_id
WHERE [...YOUR CONDITIONS]
AND post_trans.language_code = '". ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ."'";
```